# Is Delta Faucets' Warranty Really Lifetime?

Tags: faucet, delta, warranty

I was informed by an agent at Delta Faucets Canada (Masco Canada) recently that their lifetime warranty only lasts ten years for normal wear and tear.

Comment: [With caveats, yes.](https://www.deltafaucet.com/warranty) including Canada.

Comment: My Delta story is (short version): Bought a new Delta kitchen faucet from Big Orange. One part was missing. Contacted Delta - they sent a part. But it was the wrong part - apparently two variants in production of the same model of faucet. Went back to Big Orange - they were great - once they understood the problem they started opening boxes to give me the missing part from another faucet (they could have said "return the faucet for a refund or replacement", which would have been a royal pain as I was using the faucet, just couldn't mount the sprayer properly).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s off topic for the home improvement stack.

Answer (score 4):

The Delta agent's statement cited by the OP is correct only for **commercial** purchasers. The warranty time limit does not apply to individual consumers who purchase Delta products.

[The Delta warranty page](https://www.deltafaucet.com/warranty) cited by @jay613 in comments states that home consumers' warranties are not time-limited, and last as long as the original purchaser owns the house in which the item was first installed.

The Delta page states:

> All parts (other than electronic parts and batteries) and finishes of Delta® faucets purchased from authorized Delta sellers are warranted to the original consumer purchaser to be free from defects in material and workmanship for as long as the original consumer purchaser owns the home in which the faucet was first installed. For commercial purchasers, (a) the warranty period is ten (10) years for multi-family residential applications and (b) five (5) years for all other commercial applications, in each case from the date of original purchase...
>
> [Further definitions of "commercial" omitted]

Comment: I made it clear to the agent that I was the original homeowner and this was not a commercial application. She was adamant that normal wear and tear coverage expires in ten years even though, as you point out, the warranty does not say that. I sent a query to Delta to see if I get a different response. In the meantime, I bought a set of seats and springs and replaced the old ones in the cartridge, which fixed the leak I had. Cost C$3.33 from the Big Orange Box Store vs. C$80 for a new Delta branded RP19804 cartridge.

Comment: @Scubadoo The agent was wrong. It is unfortunate, and not uncommon, that the advice given by operators/agents/whoevers is incorrect.

Comment: Here is Masco's (Delta's) written reply that I just received. Apparently, their "guidelines" are not explicitly stated in their warranty, which seems very deceptive to me. "As per our warranty guidelines, Lifetime Warranty covers for any Manufacturing defects, while Parts and Finish are covered for 10 years, while electronic components are covered for 5 years." Bottom line: Delta's warranty is inferior to Moen's and Pfister's for faucets. Something to keep in mind when considering new faucets.